# Group by field(s) and aggregate on max date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have `mongo` documents of type-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("77f02ee61df85c423b6a4e79"),
    "client" : "1"
    "type" : "type1",
    "hierarchy" : "hier1",
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2015-09-09T13:06:44Z"),
    "model" : "m1"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("77f02ee61df85c423b6a4e80"),
    "client" : "1"
    "type" : "type1",
    "hierarchy" : "hier1",
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2015-09-10T14:06:44Z"),
    "model" : "m2"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("77f02ee61df85c423b6a4e81"),
    "client" : "1"
    "type" : "type1",
    "hierarchy" : "hier2",
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2015-09-10T13:06:44Z"),
    "model" : "m3"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("77f02ee61df85c423b6a4e82"),
    "client" : "2"
    "type" : "type2",
    "hierarchy" : "hier2",
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2015-09-10T14:06:44Z"),
    "model" : "m4"
}
```

I want to answer the query - For a given `client`, fetch all the latest(by `creationDate`) documents for each `type` and `hierarchy` combination (type+hierarchy).

For eg. Output for above data set for `client = 1` will look like

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("77f02ee61df85c423b6a4e80"),
    "client" : "1"
    "type" : "type1",
    "hierarchy" : "hier1",
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2015-09-10T14:06:44Z"),
    "model" : "m2"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("77f02ee61df85c423b6a4e81"),
    "client" : "1"
    "type" : "type1",
    "hierarchy" : "hier2",
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2015-09-10T13:06:44Z"),
    "model" : "m3"
}
```

I tried to create the query using given flow/pipeline-

1. `Match` the documents where `client = 1`   (`$match` inside aggregate).
2. `group` by "list" and "hierarchy"          (`$group` inside aggregate).
3. I want to aggregate the group of documents in previous step by latest `creationDate` field. Instead of applying an aggregate function `($sum, $avg etc)`, I actually want the document with latest `creationDate` field in each group

But I am stuck at point 3 in the flow. I don't know how to aggregate the documents with same `type` and `hierarchy` and select the one with latest date (`creationDate`) for each type and hierarchy in a single `mongo` query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make use of the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator inside the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage. Then include a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage if at all necessary. Use the [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) variable to keep the entire fields under a variable named `record`.

sample code:

```
db.t.aggregate([
{$match:{"client":"1"}},
{$sort:{"creationDate":-1}},
{$group:{"_id":{"type":"$type",
                "hierarchy":"$hierarchy"},
          "record":{$first:"$$ROOT"}}}
])
```

Add a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage such as the below, to get the document fields on the top level, it is not necessary and can be easily handled in the client side.

```
{$project:{"_id":0,"client":"$record.client","model":"$record.model",..}}
```