# MongoDb data query with group by first item in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I would like to run a query in mongodb using C# that is
MongoDB has a data like

```
{name: Mr X, submitted_date: 20210821},
{name: Mr Y, submitted_date: 20210920},
{name: Mr X, submitted_date: 20211010},
{name: Mr Y, submitted_date: 20210317},
{name: Mr Z, submitted_date: 20210903}
```

I want to run a query like which will return,

```
{name: Mr X, submitted_date: 20211010},
{name: Mr Y, submitted_date: 20210920},
{name: Mr Z, submitted_date: 20210903}
```

Means group by result based on latest **submitted_date**

I have write this code in C#. But cannot figure out how to take the latest submitted value and group by name.

```
    public List<Customer>(List<string> nameList)
        {
            var filter = Builders<Customer>.Filter.Empty;
            if (nameList.Count > 0)
            {
                filter = filter & Builders<Customer>.Filter.In(x => x.name, nameList);
            }
            var sort = Builders<Customer>.Sort.Descending("submitted_date");

//Should be something for my expected result
            return _collection.Find(filter).Sort(sort).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! To improve your chances of getting an answer please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you tried anything. What version of MongoDB you are using. Details about the MongoDB drivers? Here is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185493/group-by-fields-and-aggregate-on-max-date

Comment: MongoDB driver version 2.12.3

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

use this aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      submitted_date: -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$name",
      "submitted_date": {
        $first: "$submitted_date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      name: "$_id",
      submitted_date: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q_5ySZlgDOZ